# How to remove Semicolon from array in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm reading a csv file through pandas in python and the last column also includes `;` how can i remove it. if i use delimiter as `;` it does not work.

Example :

```
0    -0.22693644;
1    -0.22602014;
2     0.37201694;
3    -0.27763826;
4     -0.5549711;
Name: Z-Axis, dtype: object
```

Comment: `df['columnname'].str.rstrip(";")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use parameter `comment`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, comment=';')
```

NOTE: this will work properly only for the **last** column, as everything starting from the comment character till the end of string will be ignored

PS as a little bonus Pandas will treat such column as numeric one, not as a string.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['Z-Axis'] = df['Z-Axis'].str.rstrip(";")
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
df['Z-Axis'] = df['Z-Axis'].str[:-1]
```